# MDX Aggregate DImensions to filter

Tags: mdx, aggregation, dimension

I'm new to mdx and need your help:

```
[Item].[Segment]    [Country].[World]   [Measures].[Periodic]

   1                 Region A                  150
   2                 Region B                   60
   3                 Region C                  1400
   4                 Region D                   20
```

I have two dimensions Segment and World. If I take only world, I get no values. But I want to achieve to combine the two dimensions to one dimension on segment level as following:

```
  [Item].[Segment]  [Measures].[Periodic]    
         1                     150 
         2                     60
         3                    1400 
         4                     20
```

Would an aggregation be useful in this case?

Thanks in advance!

The Structure is like following:
[Cube_Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuzAn.jpg)

--> I need to combine both dimensions Segment and World in order to have one dimension on the row which shows me the values for the segments only!

Comment: Need more information. What's your cube structure? Please take some time to describe your question in details in order to make it answerable.

Comment: Hi. i´ve added a image of the cube structure above. Thanks!

Comment: It's not a structure. I want to see facts, their relations with dimensions. What MDX you run, etc. As much info as possible.